# i3wm: How to move windows between monitors?

Tags: window-manager, i3, multi-monitor, workspaces

In a multiple monitor set-up with i3, how do you move windows between monitors using keybindings?

Comment: This is much too broad a question and it was automatically flagged by the [se] software due to its shortness and content. Users processing the review queues won't see that it's actually a self-answered question - and may vote to close it. You should [edit] the question to include more specific details.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I've split my Q/A into two separate ones.

Comment: Splitting the question wasn’t useful and I'd suggest that you re-merge them. I was trying to say that reviewers of questions in the Close queue would not see the answer. Without knowing that it was self-answered, the question looked like a bad one and reviewers would be likely to vote to close it. I was suggesting that you include more *specific* details such as including i3wm in the *body* of the question, describe the tasks in more detail and say something like despite researching this, it wasn’t particularly obvious how to accomplish these tasks.  For useful tips, see [ask] and [answer].

Comment: In any case, I've voted to re-open this question.

Comment: This question seems fine to me. I don't see the reason it has to be expanded arbitrarily. It should be reopened in my opinion.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For windows and workspaces, you need to define a binding in your i3 config. Note: windows are called "containers", and monitors are called "outputs".

For moving windows:

`move container to output left|right|down|up|current|primary|<output>`

This is what I use in my i3 config:

```
# move focused window between monitors
bindsym $mod+Shift+greater move container to output right
bindsym $mod+Shift+less move container to output left
```

Note, you can also set a keybinding to send things to a specific monitor.

Moving focus between monitors works just like with one monitor. The focus will jump once you reach the "edge" of one monitor. The default binding is `$mod+<arrow direction>`. See also: [moving workspaces between monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397269/161652).

Comment: Is it also possible to move the focus with it?