# i3wm: How to move workspaces between monitors?

Tags: window-manager, i3, multi-monitor, workspaces

In a multiple monitor set-up, is there a way to transfer entire workspaces (as opposed to single applications) to a different monitor?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can define a binding in your i3 config. Note: windows are called "containers", and monitors are called "outputs". The relevant documentation is [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#move_to_outputs).

`move workspace to output left|right|down|up|current|primary|nonprimary|next|<output1>`

Here's what I use in my config:

```
# move focused workspace between monitors
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+greater move workspace to output right
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+less move workspace to output left
```

Strangely, I'd expect the `$mod+Ctrl+greater` to require me to hit Ctrl and Shift at the same time, since you need to press Shift to type `<` and `>`. However, pressing just mod, Ctrl, and `,` works, which is very nice.

Note, you can also set a keybinding to send things to a specific monitor by its name.

Comment: is there a way to do this using the workspace name/number? Instead of the active workspace

Comment: Good question. I don't know.

Comment: It works perfectly.

Comment: @Thayne Looks like you need to focus the appropriate workspace first (using something like `focus output primary` or other options at https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_focusing_moving_containers ). Then you can move the workspace.

Answer (score 18):

The workspace can be explicitly specified by name like this, for values of workspace_name and output_name:

```
i3-msg '[workspace="workspace_name"]' move workspace to output output_index
```

Note that if you name your workspaces like `1:first`, you use `1` not `first`.

Comment: Handy for one-off moves

Answer (score 9):

To move to the next workspace, you can use:

```
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+greater move workspace to output next
```

[docs](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#move_to_outputs)

This has the advantage of being agnostic as to the *position* of the workspace - it just cycles through them, no matter if they are up or down or whatever.